# ABCPDF - COM Exception

Tags: .net, exception, com, windows-services, abcpdf

I am using ABCPDF with my .net windows application. The version of abcpdf.net that I am using is 7.0.4.2 and I am running it on a 64bit machine. I do not have abcpdf installed on the machine though I am using the DLLS (ABCPDF.dll and ABCPDFCE7.dll). Relevent licensing information has been placed in the code. Though when my service starts to process the pdfs, I get the following exception: "Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component"
I am using the correct OS version dlls for Abcpdf.

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: E_FAIL doesn't mean anything more than "couldn't do it, don't know why".  You'll need help from the vendor.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Hans. In my case, this was occurring due to the MSDTC ports not open. Hope this helps someone else in the future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the reply Hans. In my case, this was occurring due to the MSDTC ports not open.

Comment: specifically ports 135 and 1024-65536 needed to be open.